# CronJobs - I have two cron jobs but only one works

Tags: cron

I have created 2 cron jobs on my server(ubuntu), but only one works.

```
*/5 * * * * curl -s http://www.example.com/cron.php?cron_key=TzVesnZuNqR4mkjv_LgBemUV-oYvsfYalyHOfDtL4cc

*/5 * * * * curl -s http://www.example.gr/cron.php?cron_key=OrrbXhtfSEZ2NI7BlHjAPRtMT_ENAKaz68iH86Kl5wI
```

In my log file at /var/log/syslog there is an error stating "Cron could not run because an invalid key was used." but my key is correct. When I launch manually, it runs the cron successfully.

I can't understand why this is happening. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the cron.php page requires a "cron key" to protect against
unauthorized access. Your site's cron key is automatically generated during
installation and is specific to your site. The full URL of the page, with the
cron key, is available in the "Cron maintenance tasks" section of the Status
report page at Administration > Reports > Status report.

As an example for how to set up this automated process, you can use the
crontab utility on Unix/Linux systems. The following crontab line uses the
wget command to visit the cron.php page, and runs each hour, on the hour:

0 * * * * wget -O - -q -t 1 http://example.com/cron.php?cron_key=YOURKEY

Replace the text "http://example.com/cron.php?cron_key=YOURKEY" in the
example with the full URL displayed under "Cron maintenance tasks" on the
"Status report" page.